# What are the implications of using ZoneDateTime versus Calendar, when converting and augmenting values?

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, logic, date-arithmetic

I am unsure of what unforeseeable implications, specifically invalidation, will occur when utilizing a *[Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html)* object, versus using a *[ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)* object.

I am wondering if insight can be provided to why the conversion, or parsing, of a value must be done using one framework versus the other.

I've reviewed the *Java Tutorials*, in reference to *"[legacy date-time code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/index.html)"*, and I am unable to procure where an invalidation may happen.

To paraphrase, the tutorial mentions the following.

> *"The Calendar class was not type safe".*

I am not concerned with type safety, parsing is only a few steps.

> *"Because the classes were mutable, they could not be used in multithreaded applications".*

Mutable state is not a topic.

> "Bugs in application code were common due to the unusual numbering of months and the lack of type safety".

I'm not concerned with an index versus an enumeration.

None of these points defy an antithesis for abstraction.

As a demonstration, I'll utilize both classes collectively, in an attempt to discuss their logic.

I can parse a formatted *String* value using *[SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)*, and *Calendar*.

```java
String string = "MMMM dd, yyyy '@' h:mm:ss a z";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(string);
String value = "May 28, 2023 @ 6:50:01 pm EDT";
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(format.parse(value));
```

If I print the data from *calendar* I receive a valid result.

```java
System.out.println(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.printf("%tc", calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

```
1685314201000
Sun May 28 18:50:01 EDT 2023
```

And, I could parse the same formatted *String* value using *[DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)*, and *ZonedDateTime*.
Granted, I have to uppercase the *"PM"* within *value*—this is not a set-back.
The *DateTimeParseException* had even specified a character index.

```java
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(string);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(value, format);
```

Similarly, if I print the data from *zonedDateTime*, I get a valid result.

```java
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
System.out.printf("%tc%n", zonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
```

```
1685314201000
Sun May 28 18:50:01 EDT 2023
2023-05-28T18:50:01-04:00[America/New_York]
```

If you review the data side-by-side, you'll find they are equivalent, thus both are valid.

If I wanted to augment the values, let's say, by adding 4 hours, *since EDT is UTC-4*, to derive a UTC value; I can achieve this with both classes.

For the *Calendar* class I can use the *[add](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,int))* method.
Which, has an extensible [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#field-manipulation-heading) from within the *Calendar* class.

```java
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
```

```
1685328601000
Sun May 28 22:50:01 EDT 2023
```

Equivalently, for *zonedDateTime*, I can use the *[plusHours](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#plusHours(long))* method.

```java
zonedDateTime = zonedDateTime.plusHours(4);
```

```
1685328601000
Sun May 28 22:50:01 EDT 2023
2023-05-28T22:50:01-04:00[America/New_York]
```

Again, I'm arriving at equal values, in terms of *Calendar* versus *ZonedDateTime*.

If I subtract *1,685,314,201,000* from *1,685,328,601,000*, I get *14,400,000*.
*14,400,000* is equivalent to, *4 hours* × (*60 minutes* × (*60 seconds* × *1000 milliseconds*)).

This brings me to my conclusion, on the adverse effects of using one class over another, in terms of basic parsing, and augmentation.

What is the unforeseen error that will be calculated when using one class versus the other?

For example, is one class using a more accurate year measurement, such as *365.25 days*, over *365.2425*?

Aside from the design implications stated by Java, where does one class prove as idiomatic over another—considering both will generate equivalent values.

I mean *idiomatic* from the philosophical stand-point, and not *idiomatic* in the paradigmatic, ideological, protestant way.

Empirical evidence need not apply.

Comment: No matter is using the old and cumbersome `Calendar` or the modern `ZonedDateTime` adding 4 hours to convert from EDT (North American Eastern Daylight Time) to UTC is wrong. You are getting a moment in time 4 hours later and still in Eastern Time. Both classes can do the conversion for you, though, you just need to apply UTC time zone to them.

Comment: You decide yourself whether you prefer the 5 lines or the 2 lines or which you find clearer to read. And probably nothing that matters: from `Calendar.getInstance()` you are not guaranteed to get a Gregoran calendar. Since converting between time zones or adding 4 hours is the same in all calendar systems that I can think of, it shouldn’t matter for your particular use case.

Comment: @OleV.V., I'm not concerned about design implications, which I've clearly outlined.  I'm interested in why one abstraction is considered to produce a more logical result than the other.  As you can see, there is no difference in their results, they are the exact same value.  This is now the second response which is implying that I will encounter some sort of design flaw.  Where is the flaw?  I provided the entire code which is needed to produce the result; what have I forgotten to type, there is no more logic required.  Please, apply the topic.

Comment: @OleV.V., Additionally, _"... adding 4 hours to convert ... to UTC is wrong. ... you are getting a moment in time 4 hours later and still in Eastern Time"_.  That's not correct, for the example, it's 11 am in EDT, and 3 pm at the UTC.  That is EDT plus 4.  If I understand correctly, you're saying it's because the time-zone still says EDT.  I didn't change the time-zone, though, I was simply looking to derive a UTC value.  Your saying that _that_ is the error in the logic?  That's a bit much, almost pretentious.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not using a "more accurate year measurement."  There is no aspect in which Calendar is *incorrect* or will result in values that are simply wrong.

Calendar is obsolete because it is difficult to use correctly, e.g. numbering months from 0 to 11 instead of 1 to 12.
It also conflates physical and civil times, which it's important to draw a distinction between.

It's possible to write 100% correct code with java.util.Calendar.  Most people won't, though.

Comment: So, I'm not looking for an empirical evaluation.  I'm not interested in a _"most people"_ consideration.  I'm interested in the parsing of a value, which appears to have some sort of stigma associated with it; where there is a preferred abstraction.  And, I'm failing to understand the idiomatic principle, aside from convoluted empirical stasis.  If there is no logical reason that a basic procedure cannot be done with one abstraction over another, then why would there be deferment?

Comment: Hey, if you want to write everything in assembly, because every procedure can be done in raw assembly, be my guest.  I understand you're not looking for an "empirical evaluation," but what I've told you is an accurate explanation of why people avoid java.util.Calendar, to the point that most people aren't even willing to help debug code that uses it.  What is "idiomatic," what is recommended for use by the community, is supposed to be clear to read and easy to use, and Calendar isn't, and that's _enough_ reason not to use it.

Comment: To put it another way, there is "stigma" associated with java.util.Calendar because its use is noticeably correlated with incorrect code, even if a particular example of code that uses it is correct.

Comment: I guess what the situation is, is that rather than the allusion of miscalculation, and some sort of unavoidable transcendence, it's the result of rhetoric and adherence.  Interesting, that some people choose that, over logic.  Look how deviating it is!  Were talking about calculating milliseconds and you're more than positive that one approach is better than the other.  I appreciate your time, thanks.

Comment: We'll, yes, that is my point, exactly.  What is the correlated data, which depicts the parsing of a date, executes a more logical value with one framework, versus another.  And, the answer is always the same, that _"most people"_ choose one way over another.  That's called empirical evidence, which is essentially the complete inverse of what logic defines.  It's what Descarte explains, as far as I'm concerned.  There's no time for rhetoric in logic.

Comment: So, no, you're referring to what is called a "colloquialism", and more broadly, "empiricism".  It's where there can be irrefutable proof of something, with provided logic, and there will be a non-conformance, which will poorly advise.  It's what Socrates taught, he referred to it as rhetoric.  Where, there is no logic; like a receipt at a store.  Something that is idiomatic is something that is the quality, or, the attributing factor of the logic.  So, the item that you bought, it's irrefutable, it's the logic.  The receipt is the "empirical" value; because of some undefined factor.

Comment: "Interesting, that some people choose that, over logic."  When there have been [bugs costing millions of dollars](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/dec/29/twitter-2015-date-bug) due to subtle incorrectness, I don't think this is surprising in any way.  My team has found hundreds of critical bugs caused by incorrect usage of date and time APIs, and found that their frequency is substantially reduced by using java.time.  I deny that this is surprising, wrong, or strange.

Comment: I'm talking about the parsing of a string, which I included in my question, in detail, with results.  Where is the invalid usage, and where does the ill-logic begin?  You are continuously telling me that there is some _possible_ error that may occur.  Where?  Is there an error with the calculation?  Is the _Calendar_ class using an invalid number?  Your reply is regarding using the wrong index for the month.  Where in my abstraction am I calculating a month value?  I've defined all of these aspects, yet, there is still some sort of error that _may_ happen.